# jQuery iteration of json data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with mvc4 and jQuery, I get a controller action `getJson` calling and passing a json list,

```
public JsonResult GetChildCategories(int id)
{
        Category cat = new Category(id);           
        List<Category> child = new Categories().ToList(cat);
        List<Tuple<int, string>> childList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();            

        for (int i = 0; i < child.Count; i++)
        {               
            childList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(child[i].Id, child[i].Name));
        }            

        return Json(childList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When calling this action by url, I get output like:

```
[{"Item1":3,"Item2":"Pulp Devitalizer"},{"Item1":5,"Item2":"Irrigants and conditioners"}]
```

I am trying to iterate this in each loop, but I can't:

```
  $.getJSON('/Add/GetChildCategories/' + id, function (data) {           
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
           alert(Item);
           $("<li>" + item[i][1] + "</li>").appendTo($('#' + id + ' .category-child'));             
        });
    });
```

I want to show the string part in li, when alert (item) it shows [object, object]

Comment: For the first iteration, `item.Item1` will give you "3", `item.Item2` will give you "Pulp Devitalizer"

Comment: *Tip* use `alert(JSON.stringify(item));` to see the content of item,

Comment: Y U NO try to debug before asking a question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: i got undefined

Comment: Then `data` is not `[{"Item1":3,"Item2":"Pulp Devitalizer"}, ...]`!

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `item[i][1]` does not make sense. An array of objects is looped with the `$.each` function. Argument i refers to the index of the element within the array, item refers to the element within the array (in this case the object). The object, however, has two fields that can be addressed with `item.Item1` and `Item.Item2`.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1j57qvh8/) to see an example with your code and notice that `item.Item1` returns a value and `item[0]` not (undefined).

Hope this will help.